# FATAL ERROR: WP complains about redeclaration

Tags: plugins, wpdb, fatal-error

I'm making a plugin with multiple files, and it have some interation with wpdb so i've put everything in one file named FA-db.php

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
function FAvideoid()
{
    return $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT 'video_id' FROM $wpdb->ytvideos ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;");
}
function FAregister($id)
{
    $wpdb->insert( 'ytvideos', $id, '%s' );
}

function FAsetup()
{
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "ytvideos"; 
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name ( id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, video_id varchar(55) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, UNIQUE KEY id (id))     $charset_collate;";
    dbDelta( $sql );
}
?>
```

and include it in my main file

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Floating Ads
Description: A floating ad that have youtube ads built in
Version: 0.5.0
Author: Henrique Almeida Marcomini
*/
include "FA-db.php";
include "FA-admin.php";
include "FA-ad.php";
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'FAmenu' );
add_action( 'wp', 'FAad' );
add_action( 'activated_plugin', 'FAsetup' );  
?>
```

and i do not include it anywhere else.

But when i try to activate the plugin i get the following error

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare FAvideoid() (previously declared in /home/u696621553/public_html/wp-content/plugins/FloatingAds/FA-db.php:7) in /home/u696621553/public_html/wp-content/plugins/FloatingAds/FA-db.php on line 8
```

Comment: I've voted for close this question because it is a error from PHP, nothing related with WordPress. So, [it is off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It seems that you have declared the same function, `FAvideoid()`, more than once. You should search the code in all your files looking for that function, you will find it more than once for sure.

Comment: I've already searched, and found nothing. thats why i think its a wordpress issue. I had even changed the name of the function to "daesdxgbf" to see if it was not the name, but the problemn persist

Comment: Try `include_once` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your function with [`!function_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) to avoid a redeclare error.

```
if( ! function_exists('FAvideoid') ) :

  function FAvideoid()
  {
      return $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT 'video_id' FROM $wpdb->ytvideos ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;");
  }

endif;
```

Or to reduce the code from being imported more than once:

```
include_once "FA-db.php";
include_once "FA-admin.php";
include_once "FA-ad.php";
```

But probably the best route is to mix the two:

```
// Only load files and hook events if your functions haven't been defined

if( ! function_exists('FAvideoid') ) :

    include_once "FA-db.php";
    include_once "FA-admin.php";
    include_once "FA-ad.php";

    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'FAmenu' );
    add_action( 'wp', 'FAad' );
    add_action( 'activated_plugin', 'FAsetup' );

endif;
```

Comment: it did worked, making it really a doble include. But why? since i do not use include "FA-db.php"; anywhere else in my whole code.

Comment: You can always write to the debug.log to check if you are in fact loading it twice.

Comment: This solution avoids the fatal error but it is **very bad approach**. The OP doesn't know where the original funciton is declared, so it is impossible to know what the triggered function does. And so, it is impossible to know exactly what the plugin does. Hiding the error is very very bad and it is not a solution. Take the time to fully know the code you are writting and what it does.

Comment: @cybmeta - You can still track down the source of the problem with the added luxury of not seeing this redeclare error. If you have the folder duplicated in the `/plugins/` directory then you would see this issue. Some minor use of http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php would find the origin pretty quickly. Keep in mind, if you have a library of classes used in multiple places you would use this approach to only declare the classes/functions once.

Comment: If you use `! function_exists()` as you describe, in the context of this question, the error message disappear and the original function is used, not the one written by the OP. And the OP doesn't know the original function, so he can not trust on what his plugin does. That is why I think is a terrible solution for the OP. I hope you understand what I'm trying to explain and why I think this is not a solution for the problem in the context of this question.

Comment: @cybmeta - I do, and I appreciate your opinion as well. I'd suggest working through the problem with the OP to find a better solution to the root cause.